# how to use ASP.NET Membership API in a web service ( newbie question)

Tags: asp.net

I have a database where membership information is being controlled by the ASP.NET membership api. I need to access this info from a web service as well. Can I just use the membership classes or is there is some restriction that says these classes can only be used in a page\aspx kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Membership API where ever you like, but I would think heavily on whether or not you can secure your web services sufficiently that they cannot be abused, and by abused I mean someone coming in and pounding your web services to lock out accounts, guess user names and passwords, and exploit whatever other functionality you wish to provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these classes, but you need to mark your WebService methods with a special attribute, to [enable Session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx).

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
```